# how to plot shape only specific time frame in pine script?

Tags: pine-script-v5

to have a condition based plot shape only on 1 minute time frame , so the flag only on one minute not even 2 minute or higher or less ??
for example if in on minute time frame

volume > 1000
plot shape()
I will be grateful if someone help on this

Answer (score 1):

you can use `timeframe.multiplier`  (Return Type is  simple int ) Multiplier of resolution, e.g. '60' - 60, 'D' - 1, '5D' - 5, '12M' - 12

or `timeframe.period` (Return Type is simple string ) Resolution, e.g. '60' - 60 minutes, 'D' - daily, 'W' - weekly, 'M' - monthly, '5D' - 5 days, '12M' - one year, '3M' - one quarter.

in your case any of the following can be used:

```
plotshape(timeframe.multiplier==1 and your_condition_true , style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red)

plotshape(timeframe.period=='1' and your_condition_true , style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red)
```